# The collection type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Guid,System.String]' is not supported. in .net core 3.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.1, versionupgrade

I have project .net core 2.2.

in 2.2 my controller's return type is `List<Dictionary<Guid, string>>`.

When I upgrade my project to 3.1 it returns the error message.

```
System.NotSupportedException
  HResult=0x80131515
  Message=The collection type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Guid,System.String]' is not supported.
  Source=System.Text.Json
```

Why is this error message showing?
How to fix it?

Comment: Post your code. Both .NET Core 2 and .NET Core 3 are out of support anyway, for a *long* time. The oldest supported version is .NET 6. You may be hitting a bug that was fixed years ago in .NET 6

Comment: When you switched from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1 you switched serializers to System.Text.Json.  And **in .NET Core 3.1** this serializer did not support dictionaries with a `Guid` key, see  see [Dictionary with non-string key](https://web.archive.org/web/20221022215653/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#dictionary-with-non-string-key): *The built-in support for dictionary collections in System.Text.Json in .NET Core 3.1 is limited to `Dictionary<string, TValue>`. That is, the key must be a string.*

Comment: The workaround in that version was to write a converter, but .NET Core 3.1 went out of support on December 13, 2022 so the proper fix would be to upgrade to a supported version of .NET (i.e. .NET 6 or later), since the limitation was removed as far back as [.NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-next-for-system-text-json/#new-features).  Should I make that an answer?

Comment: Hmm, looks like the query parameter and fragment delimiter don't work with wayback machine.  Follow this link for [Dictionary with non-string key](https://web.archive.org/web/20221022215653/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft), select ".NET Core 3.1" and search for "Dictionary with non-string key".

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Adam Vincent answer. If you want to keep using `Newtonsoft.Json` in .NET Core 3 you have to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package and in your `Startup.cs` call `AddNewtonsoftJson()`.

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in upgrading to .NET Core 3, you have inadvertently switched JSON serializers.  The primary JSON serializer in the early days of .NET Core was `NewtonSoft.Json`, then the dotnet team created `System.Text.Json`.

`System.Text.Json`, at the time of .NET Core 3 had limited type support. If I recall correctly, at that time it only supported primitive types like `int`, `string`, `bool`. It is very likely that `IList<T>` wasn't supported at that time.  The short answer is try using `Newtonsoft.Json` instead to serialize / deserialize this type. The long answer is don't use a version of .NET that has long passed its life cycle.

Comment: `List<T>` has always been supported by System.Text.Json.  But in .NET Core 3.1 the only support dictionary key type was `string`, see [Dictionary with non-string key](https://web.archive.org/web/20221022215653/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#dictionary-with-non-string-key): *The built-in support for dictionary collections in System.Text.Json in .NET Core 3.1 is limited to `Dictionary<string, TValue>`. That is, the key must be a string.*

Comment: Nice archeological find! Thanks for providing the context.  The link doesn't appear to work unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, looks like the query parameter and fragment delimiter don't work with wayback machine.  Follow this link for [Dictionary with non-string key](https://web.archive.org/web/20221022215653/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft), select ".NET Core 3.1" and search for "Dictionary with non-string key".